# Segmentation Fault when referring from another process to an element a memalloced pointer points at

Tags: c, linux, pointers, malloc, shared-memory

I have a "Server" and a "Client" process, they "communicate" through a struct shared memory.

```
typedef struct
{
  char* buffer;
  int cards;
  int maxCards;
}  myStruct
```

Both "Server" and "Client" processes can get/set the values of the two int types, but the thing is different with the buffer (we use this as a pointer to chars): the "Server" allocates memory, like:

```
(*sharedMem).buffer = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*maxCards);
```

has the ability to set or get values:

```
(*sharedMem).buffer[0] = 'a';
printf("%c\n",(*sharedMem).buffer[0]);
```

but when the "Client" process tries to access a char:

```
printf("%c\n",(*sharedMem).buffer[0])
```

It collapses with Segmentation Fault Core Dumped error.
Is there a way to solve this problem without using an Array or List? Any Ideas?

Comment: Both processes have different address spaces, so pointers in one may be meaningless in the other?

Comment: Why can't you use an array or a list? Because using an array for the buffer is exactly the solution you need.

Comment: @Jens is there any way I can send the pointed adresses to the "Client" process?

Comment: @FUZxxl That is a solution and if I cannot change adresses between the processes, I'll use a list.

Comment: Found the answer, this question was already answered:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14558443/c-shared-memory-dynamic-array-inside-shared-struct

Comment: @MEZesUBI Not really. Instead of pointers, you can use “message numbers” or something like that and then send over a set of messages. Generally, try to avoid using pointers when sending data over the nentwork. But why did you exclude arrays in your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both processes have different address spaces, so pointers in one are generally meaningless in the other (except for possibly `NULL`).

If you need to exchange more data between processes, you could use

- pipes (see the `pipe()` system call)
- shared memory (see POSIX shm* calls)
- memory mapped files (see `mmap()`)
- use an array-of-char in your struct