# Is this answer to [How to include a dynamic array INSIDE a struct in C?] correct?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Could someone tell me if this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2061038) is correct!?
I'm not sure about the allocation of the second struct:

`struct dyn_array my_array = malloc(sizeof(struct dyn_array) + 100 * sizeof(int));`

Shouldn't `my_array` be a pointer, like this:

`struct dyn_array *my_array = malloc(sizeof(struct dyn_array) + 100 * sizeof(int));`

Comment: Yes, it should be a pointer.

Comment: you are correct. It seems typo.

Comment: Yes. It's been fixed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be a comment