# Cast buffer to structure pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have a buffer and want to cast it as pointer to structure:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct __attribute__((packed)) req {
    uint8_t a;
    uint16_t b;
    uint8_t *c;
};


void f(uint8_t *Buf)
{
    struct req *r = (struct req *)Buf;

    printf("a: %02x\n", r->a);
    printf("b: %04x\n", r->b);
    printf("c: %02x\n", r->c[0]);

}

int main()
{
    uint8_t buf[] = {0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04 };

    f(buf);

    return 0;
}
```

The example won't work because the 4th byte is not address, but the actual data. I can "fix" this by manually set pointer:

```
r->c = &Buf[3];
```

Is there any way to do this with a cast?

Comment: I don't know of any hardware where a pointer is a single byte, so for a starter the buffer is too small. And making the pointer point to itself doesn't solve *anything*. It's more like a band-aid on a broken leg. What are you **really** trying to do here?

Comment: If you want an array inside the struct, perhaps you meant `uint8_t c[1];`?

Comment: No, that's undefined behaviour. By assigning to `r->c`, you are both clobbering the very buffer contents you are trying to point to and writing past the end of the array `buf`. In `f`, you could do `struct rec r;` `r.a = Buf[0];` `r.b = Buf[1] | (Buf[2] << 8); /* assuming little-endian */` `r.c = &Buf[3];`.

Comment: In addition to what others have said, accessing byte array through incompatible struct members is a *strict aliasing violation*, which is also undefined behaviour. Don't do that.

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: To avoid UB due to strict aliasing issues, you should allocate the buffer dynamically (malloc). Personally, I use alloca (nonstandard) for this kind of stuff and hope for the best.

Comment: And possible unaligned access too... which is yet another kind of UB, though here the `packed` would make compiler to mostly generate code that is packed too...

Comment: If you intend to just send a piece of memory to disk or network, you must ensure it's just one piece of memory. Using a pointer like `c` virtually ensures that you have two pieces: one piece that contains `c`, the other piece that `c` points to. One possible solution is to declare `c` as `uint8_t c[MAX_C_SIZE]`. Then the contents of `c` is part of the same piece of memory as `a` and `b`. Of course, that opens you to all sorts of nastiness if you overrun the `c`'s boundary.

Comment: I'm trying to parse communication protocol, where is c is variable length payload. I'll just remove the pointer from the structure and assign it manually.

Comment: @StefanMavrodiev note that the criticism above was not *limited* to the flexible array member / pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any way to do this with a cast?

No, for many reasons:

- As you say, the byte stream does not correspond to the struct. The last item is not a pointer. The only time when you can use a cast is when you know that the actual data stored at the target location is of the same type as the destination variable.
- The cast invokes undefined behavior since it violates [the strict aliasing rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule). Anything can happen.
- The various data in the byte stream seems misaligned, which may or may not be an issue depending on system.

In this case, you have to manually de-serialize the data:

```
struct req r = { buf[0], 
                 (uint16_t)buf[1]<<8 | buf[2], // assumes big endian
                 &buf[3] };
```

And here we notice that the code is also endianess-dependent. So you must know the endianess of the system/protocol where this data came from, in order to correctly de-serialize it.

Comment: I did the same thing, except my system is little-endian.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to do this with a cast?

Yes it is possible, with the following assumptions:

- You need to take care of the struct alignment (compiler specific):
  `#pragma pack(push, 1) ... #pragma pack(pop)`,
  `__attribute__((packed))`, etc.
- You need to take care of the endianess between your architecture and the bytes in a buffer (make a conversion if needed)

What you can do is to use `void* c` instead of `uint8_t* c` in the struct and then cast `void*` to a explicit pointer type.

#### Example 1:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma pack(push, 1)
typedef struct {
    uint8_t a;
    uint16_t b;
    void* c;
} req;
#pragma pack(pop)

void f(uint8_t* Buf)
{
    req* r = (req*)Buf;
    printf("a: %02x\n", r->a);
    printf("b: %04x\n", r->b);
    printf("c: %02x\n", ((uint8_t*)&r->c)[0]);
}
int main()
{
    uint8_t buf[] = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04 };
    f(buf);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
a: 01
b: 0302
c: 04
```

#### Example 2:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma pack(push, 1)
typedef struct {
    uint8_t a;
    uint16_t b;
    void* c;
} req;

typedef struct {
    uint8_t cmd;
    uint16_t value;
} SubPacket;
#pragma pack(pop)

void f(uint8_t* Buf)
{
    req* r = (req*)Buf;

    printf("a: %02x\n", r->a);
    printf("b: %04x\n", r->b);

    SubPacket* sub_packet = (SubPacket*)&r->c;

    printf("cmd: %02x\n", sub_packet->cmd);
    printf("value: %04x\n", sub_packet->value);

}

int main()
{
    uint8_t buf[] = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07 };

    f(buf);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
a: 01
b: 0302
cmd: 04
value: 0605
```

Comment: *What you can do is to use `void* c` instead of `uint8_t* c` in the struct and then cast `void*` to a explicit pointer type.*  That makes absolutely no difference - it's still a violation of strict aliasing.  [And dangerous even on supposedly-safe x86 systems where "it works"...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46790550/c-undefined-behavior-strict-aliasing-rule-or-incorrect-alignment)

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct __attribute__((packed)) req {
    uint8_t a;
    uint16_t b;
    uint8_t c[]; /* <--- Use this notation to be able to achieve this */
};


void f(uint8_t *Buf)
{
    struct req *r = (struct req *)Buf;

    printf("a: %02x\n", r->a);
    printf("b: %04x\n", r->b);
    printf("c: %02x\n", r->c[0]);

}

int main()
{
    uint8_t buf[] = {0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04 };

    f(buf);

    return 0;
}
```

Look here: [How to include a dynamic array INSIDE a struct in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060974/how-to-include-a-dynamic-array-inside-a-struct-in-c)

Comment: It might just work, or it might not work. (I didn't downvote)

Comment: I would argue that it works, at least it does with pointers to allocated memory.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060974/how-to-include-a-dynamic-array-inside-a-struct-in-c

Comment: It is a strict-aliasing violation though