# Can malloc be relied on to return contiguous memory, and how do I properly call it?

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management

Before I get started, yes I have read [a possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625270/does-malloc-allocate-a-contiguous-block-of-memory), [malloc being weird in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625270/does-malloc-allocate-a-contiguous-block-of-memory), [cplusplus.com on malloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/) and done some searching on google.

I have a scientific computing problem that requires a very large 2D array. I'm following code found in a copy of "Numerical Recipes in C", and am having a problem with unallocated memory in the middle of my 2D array.  I am working in Windows, and am using c++ with MSVC 2012.

Here is my 2D array allocation

```
  unsigned long nrl=0;
  unsigned long nrh=749774;
  unsigned long ncl=0
  unsigned long nch=250657;
  unsigned long i, nrow=nrh-nrl+1,ncol=nch-ncl+1;
  double **m;
  if((size_t)(nrow*ncol)<(size_t)nrow){
    m=NULL;
    return m;
  }
  /*allocate pointers to rows*/
  m=(double **)malloc((size_t)(nrow)*sizeof(double*));
  if (!m){
    m=NULL;
    return m;
  }

  /*allocate rows and set pointers to them*/
  m[nrl]=(double *) malloc((size_t)((nrow*ncol)*sizeof(double)));
  if(!m[nrl]){  
    free(m[nrl]);
    free(m);
    m=NULL;
    return m;
  }
  for(i=nrl+1;i<=nrh;i++)m[i]=m[i-1]+ncol;
  /*The 2D array should now be callable as m[nrow][ncol]*/
  /*Pseudo-code below*/
  m[0][0] == Good, allocated memory
  m[125][200923] == Unallocated, crashes program
  m[nrh-1][nch-1] == Good, allocated memory
```

I am currently relying on malloc to return NULL if memory allocation fails (I do actually get NULL values if I try to allocate very very large arrays.

Also, I have attempted `double *m = new double[nch*nrh]`, but that gives me a memory allocation error. I am open to any suggestions for alternative implementations, but I need to be able to know whether the allocation works and reallocate a smaller block if necessary.

EDIT:

This is a c function, but the majority of my code is in c++.

UPDATE:

Thanks to David, I was able to fix the problem. Changing my overflow check from

```
if((size_t)(nrow*ncol)<(size_t)nrow)
```

to

```
if(SIZE_MAX/nrow < ncol || SIZE_MAX/ncol < nrow || nrow*ncol<nrow)
```

allows malloc to fail when it should.

Comment: awell you are trying to allocate 1.36 tebibytes of data so yeah, that'll give you a meory allocation error.

Comment: Makes more sense to `((size_t)nrow)*((size_t)ncol)` than `(size_t)(nrow*ncol)`.

Comment: no need to cast i think. they are `int` eventually. you should pay attention to overflow problem instead if the array is big. and if it's big, i think you don't need to consider the continuous allocation too, since you want it to be continuous only when all of your data fits in the cache.

Comment: It is very unfortunate that you are using MSVC because they are not standard conforming. With a real modern C compiler you have real 2D dynamic matrices and you don't have to use these fake matrices that you are using. In C99 this would just be `double (*m)[ncol] = malloc(sizeof(double[nrow][ncol]));`. No multiple allocation, no explcit size computation, ... Also don't use a C++ compiler to compile C. These are two different languages.

Comment: @JensGustedt It's not so much the choice of MSVC that has led to this, rather the fact that the code comes from NR and is utterly ancient.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan NR **is** ancient, and I promise to find a more modern solution next time.

Comment: @Riet NR has its place. Eigen is pretty tasty. Out of interest, what is the problem at hand?

Comment: It's to calculate the conductivity of a battery electrode with the current collector still attached, including probe geometry and 3D effects. There's an analytical solution, but it requires a lot of Fourier terms and this matrix is to find the Fourier coefficients. We're working on exactly how many we need and can use, thus the ridiculous matrix size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing that you have a 32 bit process. Do note that `nrow*ncol*sizeof(double)` is (a lot!) greater than 2^32. You are actually attempting to allocate 1400 GB, which I rather imagine comes as a surprise to you.

It's most likely not possible to allocate that much memory, and certainly not in a 32 bit process. Your code appears to run because `(nrow*ncol)*sizeof(double)` suffers from integer overflow and so your call to `malloc` succeeds but doesn't allocate the memory that you expect it to. In fact, even in a 64 bit process you have overflow, because `nrow*ncol` is evaluated with 32 bit arithmetic because you declared `nrow` and `ncol` to be `unsigned long`. They should really be `size_t`.

Anyway, you are going to need to reconsider your entire approach to your problem. Can you really expect to do anything useful with a 1400 GB dense matrix?

Comment: Note: DOS 16-bit machines (in huge memory model) can allocate > 64k memory.  IOW, being a "32 bit machine" does not limit memory to 4Gbyte.  Memory capacity, though typically related to possessor integer size, are independent factors.

Comment: 32 or 64 bit doesn't really matter in this case...Sure you CAN fit 1.36 tebibytes in a 64 bit address space, but Windows 8 only supports up to 512 gibibytes. Windows Server 2012 can support up to 4 tebibibytes, but I'd guess if the person could afford that hardware the question would be very different.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams Well, it kind of does matter in that the failure mode is different. On 64 bit the call to malloc would fail because at least the `size_t` that was passed was the intended value.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams Well, that's modulo first converting nrow and ncol to be `size_t`.

Comment: If `size_t` is 64 bit and `long` is 32, overflow occurs with `nrow*ncol` before casting to 64-bit.

Comment: @chux Yes, I realised that too

Comment: Very much appreciated. I realized that it shouldn't be able to allocate that much memory, and that I probably wouldn't really need that much anyways. I expected this piece of code to return NULL so that I could reallocate and make it small enough to fit in available resources. Again, many thanks!

Comment: On a 64-bit system, `unsigned long` can be either 32 or 64 bits. I think it's usually 64 bits on Linux, 32 on Windows.

Comment: @Keith That's right but we knew this was Windows because question mentions msvc. So I took that fact implicitly.